# CMUSphinx Training acoustic model very low accuracy

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I've followed tutorial https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/ to train a new acoustic model for my Vietnamese language. Simply, I've recorded digits from 0 to 9 to train and also used these trained data to test. Therefore, the accuracy should be 100% as expected. However, it's only about 20% (only recognize 2 and 3). I've re-recorded many times but it's not changed. I can make sure that I do exactly all requirement such as 16k sample rate, 16 bit depth,...

Could anyone give me some explanation and the way to improve my model? Thank y'all

Here is my project: https://github.com/legiaquy/test

Answer (score 0):

Training data is not sufficient. According to [tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/) you need:

> - **1 hour of recording** for command and control for a single speaker
> - 5 hours of recordings of 200 speakers for command and control for many speakers
> - 10 hours of recordings for single speaker dictation
> - 50 hours of recordings of 200 speakers for many speakers dictation

You can get Vietnamese data from https://github.com/undertheseanlp/automatic_speech_recognition